# How to view the command line and environment variables for a process in the linux command line

Tags: linux, process, environment-variables, centos

I'd like to be able to see both the command line that launch a given process (by PID) and the its environment variables.

Preferably from a command line but a script would be acceptable failing that.

This would be on Centos 5.3 but the more widely it works the better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cat /proc/$pid/environ
cat /proc/$pid/cmdline
```

where $pid is the pid you are interested in

Comment: Note that these are NUL-delimited sequences of strings and are informational only; they may be wrong if the process has overwritten its `argv`/`environ` memory.

Comment: `| xargs -0 -n1 echo` could be added for readability of the output

Answer (score 0):

`ps -ef` is a quick way to get the command line args for everything. grep to your hearts delight!